# How to Bind data from Razor to Knockout?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js

I am using KnockOut JS and MVC.

How do I bind the data from @ RAZOR view to my databind in KO.

I tried doing this but did not return anything at the CONTROLLER.

What I am trying to achieve here is that the Razorview renders the rows in Step3(View).I want to bind these rows to the KNOCKOUT so that I can pass this data to the Step4(View).

Is there a better way??

**VIEW:**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:ApprTable">
                @for (int i = 0; i < UserWRInfo.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>

                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.submit.bind($data,'@i')">Start</button>
                        </td>
                      <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="value: Appropriation">@UserWRInfo[i].AppropriationNumber</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="value: PriorityDate">@UserWRInfo[i].PriorityDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="value: Location">@UserWRInfo[i].Sect @UserWRInfo[i].Township @UserWRInfo[i].Range@UserWRInfo[i].RangeDirectionID</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="value: Source">@UserWRInfo[i].Source</td>
                        @if (UserWRInfo.Count == UserOwner.Count)
                        {
                            <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="value: Owner">@UserOwner[i].ToString()</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="value: Owner"></td>
                        }

                        <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="value: Use">@UserWRInfo[i].UseDescription</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="value: StartedBy"></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="value: RequiredReporting">@UserWRInfo[i].isAnnualReportRequired</td>
                    </tr>

                }

            </tbody>
```

**JS:**

```
function RowData(Appropriation, PriorityDate, Location, Source, Owner, Use, StartedBy, RequiredReporting) {
    var self = this;

    self.Appropriation = ko.observable(Appropriation);
    self.PriorityDate = ko.observable(PriorityDate);
    self.Location = ko.observable(Location);
    self.Source = ko.observable(Source);
    self.Owner = ko.observable(Owner);
    self.Use = ko.observable(Use);
    self.StartedBy = ko.observable(StartedBy);
    self.RequiredReporting = ko.observable(RequiredReporting);
}

function Step3ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.ApprTable = ko.observableArray();
    self.ApprTable.push(RowData());
    self.submit = function (buttonid) {
        var ApprData = ko.toJSON(self.ApprTable());

        $.post("/Step/Step4", { "AD": ApprData }, function (data) {
        }, 'json');
    }

}

ko.applyBindings(new Step3ViewModel());
```

Comment: Check this article http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/using-web-api-with-entity-framework,-part-5 . Basically you need to move code which retrieves data from to server to action which returns json or xml result and then get this data from the server using ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a single element observable array by calling the `RowData` constructor, but you're not passing any parameters in.

```
self.ApprTable = ko.observableArray([new RowData()]);
```

The function definition requires a lot of parameters

```
function RowData(Appropriation, PriorityDate, Location, Source, Owner, Use, StartedBy, RequiredReporting)
```

You're not actually putting any data into the observables.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the stuff. If you want to init the view from razor data, you can do it in two ways:

First, generate JSON in the controller and load it to knockout view model using "knockout-mapping" plugin, for example your view may contain:

> ```
> <script>
>     $(function () {
>         ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(ViewBag.jmodel), null, viewModel);
>     });
> </script>
> ```

of course you should prepare `ViewBag.jmodel` in your controller, like this:

```
JsonSerializer js = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings());
var jw = new StringWriter();
js.Serialize(jw, <your object here>);
ViewBag.jmodel = jw.ToString();
```

Other way is to generate code that will add data row by row like you attempted to do:

> ```
> var viewModel=new Step3ViewModel();
> ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
>
> @for (int i = 0; i < UserWRInfo.Count; i++)
> {
>   viewModel.ApprTable.push(new RowData(@UserWRInfo[i].AppropriationNumber, /*other values here to create full row of data row*/)
> }
> ```

This way will generate as many `viewModel.ApprTable.push(...)` lines as you have in your data set.

And of course, your table with data and knockout binding should NOT contain any razor code!!!

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:ApprTable">
...
    <td style="text-align: center" data-bind="value: Appropriation"></td>
...
</tbody>
```

Comment: You got me wrong I updated what I want in the question.I am using Razor for step3 while I want to bind KO to send to step4 view.

Comment: You have set data-bind for the table to fill the data from knockout viewmodel and at the same time you are filling the whole table from Razor. You should choose one method - either you will fill the whole table on the server using Razor or you will send JSON data to your form and fill the table using knockout.