# Send Data from View to Controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have a VIEW which renders data from ViewData as shown below into a table.

As you can see there is a button for each row.

I want to send the Row data to the controller for that corresponding button when clicked.

How do I achieve this?

Please help with suggestion and best methodologies to implement this.

I tried using knockout to bind this data and post it to controller as I posted in this [How to Bind data from Razor to Knockout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395508/how-to-bind-data-from-razor-to-knockout) it did not work nothing gets binded.

**VIEW**

```
@{
    var UserWRInfo = (List<InfoEntity>)ViewData["UserWRInfo"];
    var UserOwner = (List<string>)ViewData["UserOwner"];

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ><b>Status</b></th>
                <th ><b>Appropriation</b></th>
                <th ><b>PriorityDate</b></th>
                <th ><b>Location</b></th>
                <th ><b>Source</b></th>
                <th ><b>Owner</b></th>
                <th ><b>Use</b></th>
                <th ><b>StartedBy</b></th>
                <th ><b>RequiredReporting</b></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < UserWRInfo.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button></td>
                    <td> @UserWRInfo[i].AppropriationNumber</td>
                    <td> @UserWRInfo[i].PriorityDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
                    <td> @UserWRInfo[i].Sect @UserWRInfo[i].Township @UserWRInfo[i].Range@UserWRInfo[i].RangeDirectionID</td>
                    <td> @UserWRInfo[i].Source</td>
                    @if (UserWRInfo.Count == UserOwner.Count)
                    {
                        <td> @UserOwner[i].ToString()</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td ></td>
                    }

                    <td> @UserWRInfo[i].UseDescription</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td> @UserWRInfo[i].isAnnualReportRequired</td>
                </tr>

            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using ViewData rather than binding to a model?

Comment: Since this is a an open-ended question, for starters try removing all your inline styling which will make for much more readable code and separates your concerns.

Comment: Nothing particular about it I found this to be an easy way to get a list of the model objects.

Comment: Do you want to achieve this using using AJAX or are you not fussed?

Comment: I just updated the question with a link to how i tried to use knockout js to bind the data and send it to controller which hasnt worked.

Comment: @sss111: `ViewBag`/`ViewData` is evil. They are dynamic, which means they aren't evaluated until runtime. If there's a bug in your code, it could show up at any point, and you'll have no idea unless you're using an error logging solution, and even then, your user has already been affected, which could result in lost sales or detrimental effects to other KPIs. If your application is going to fail, you want it to fail at *compile*, so avoid dynamics like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

Try make this way

```
<tbody>

    @for (int i = 0; i < UserWRInfo.Count; i++)
{
    <form name="form_@i" method="post" action="Controller/Action">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="@UserWRInfo[i].AppropriationNumber">@*repeate for each attribute*@
            </td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button></td>
            <td> @UserWRInfo[i].AppropriationNumber</td>
            <td> @UserWRInfo[i].PriorityDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
            <td> @UserWRInfo[i].Sect @UserWRInfo[i].Township @UserWRInfo[i].Range@UserWRInfo[i].RangeDirectionID</td>
            <td> @UserWRInfo[i].Source</td>
            @if (UserWRInfo.Count == UserOwner.Count)
            {
                <td> @UserOwner[i].ToString()</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td></td>
            }

            <td> @UserWRInfo[i].UseDescription</td>
            <td></td>
            <td> @UserWRInfo[i].isAnnualReportRequired</td>
        </tr>
    </form>
}

</tbody>
```

Comment: `<form>` inside `<tbody>`? That doesn't seem like the best idea

Comment: Is the faster solution, but i agree that not the better idea, but works fine, if him don't figure out other way

Comment: It does not "work fine". `<form>` inside of `<tbody>` is invalid, and while most browsers may correct your bad HTML for you, you should *never* rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally start by creating a view model in C# that gets passed down to the view like so:

```
public class ViewModel //choose a name that fits the data/business case
{

    public IList<UserInfo> UserInfo { get; set; }
}

public class UserInfoViewModel
{
    //Note: your datatypes may vary
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Appropriation { get; set; }
    // continue with all other properties ...
}
```

I'd then pass this model from the controller to the view:

```
public class HomeController
{
     [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
         var viewModel = new ViewModel();
         viewModel.UserInfo = new List<UserInfo>();
         // build your collection...

         return View(viewModel);
     }
}
```

From here, I'd probably use Knockout.js or Angular.js or some other data binding framework on the view.  Here's how it would look with Knockout.js:

```
// Your View Code Here...
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <!-- table header, etc... -->

   <tbody data-bind="foreach: userInfo">
       <td><button data-bind="click: sendToServer"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: appropriation"></td>

       <!-- add all other fields via data-bind -->

   </tbody>

</table>

@{
     System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    var UserInfo = function(json){

        self.Status = ko.observable(json.Status);
        self.Appropriation = ko.observable(json.Approiation);

        // continue with all other properties

        self.sendToServer = function(userData){
           // your ajax to send to server, however, I'd probably inject a data access object
        }

    };


    var ViewModel = function(json) {

        var self = this;
        self.userInfo = ko.observableArray();

        self.setUserInfo = function(){
          //using underscore.js
          _.each(json.UserInfo, function(userInfoJson){
              var userInfo = new UserInfo(userInfoJson);

              self.userInfo.push(userInfo);
          });
        };

    };

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var viewModel = new ViewModel(@Html.Raw(serializer.Serialize(Model));

        viewModel.setUserInfo();

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    });

</script>
```